# Prove that such an inverse is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Given $z$ is a non zero complex number, we define a new complex number $z^{-1}$ , called $z$ inverse to have the property that $z\cdot z^{-1} = 1$

$z^{-1}$  is also often written as $1/z$

Comment: Try proof by contradiction?

Comment: You can format the mathematics using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever you need to prove the uniqueness of an element that holds some property, you can begin your proof by assuming the existence of *at least* two such elements that hold this property, say $x$ and $y$, and showing that under this assumption, it turns out $x = y$, necessarily.

In this case, the property we'll check is "being an inverse of $z$": We'll use the definition of $z$-inverse (the inverse of $z$): it is "any" element $z'$ such that $$z' z = zz' = 1\tag{1}$$ (We won't denote any such element by $z^{-1}$ yet, because we have to first rule out the possibility that such an element is not unique.)

---

So suppose $z \neq 0 \in \mathbb C$ has two inverses, $x, y,\;\;x\neq y$. We won't call either of them $z^{-1}$ at this point because we are assuming they are distinct, and that they are *both* inverses satisfying $(1)$.

Then we use the definition of an inverse element, $(1)$, which must hold for both $x, y$. Then

- Since $y$ is an inverse of $z$, we must have, by $(1)$ that $\color{blue}{\bf yz} = zy = \color{blue}{\bf 1}$, and
- Since $x$ is an inverse of $z$, we must have that $xz = \color{blue}{\bf zx = 1}$, again, so it satisfies the definition of an inverse element given in $(1)$.

This means that $${\bf{x}} = \color{blue}{\bf 1} \cdot x = \color{blue}{\bf(yz)}x = y(zx) =\;y\color{blue}{\bf (zx)} = y \cdot \color{blue}{\bf 1} = {\bf {y}}$$

Hence, $$\text{Therefore,}\quad x \;=\; y \;= \;z^{-1},$$ 
and thus, there really is *only one* multiplicative inverse of $z;\;$ that is, the inverse of a given complex $z$ must be unique, and we denote it by $\,z^{-1}.$

Answer (score 7):

Hints: suppose $\,a,b\,$ inverses to the same non-zero $\,z\in\Bbb C\,$ :

$$a=a\cdot 1=a(zb)=(az)b=\ldots$$

Comment: is it common courtesy to not provide straight forward answers on this site or is it not allowed?

Comment: Most of the times yes, in particular when question have the sign of "homework" on them...

Answer (score 0):

Show that the identity element in a group $G$ is unique; that is there exists only one element $e\in G$ such that $eg=ge=g$ for all $g\in G$.